# Make search array search in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, filter, find

I have data in JSON format here

```
[{
    "groupID": 1,
    "name": "admin",
    "remarks": "access group name,"
},
{
    "groupID": 111,
    "name": "member",
    "remarks": "access group name"
}]
```

i need filtering data from all field JSON example when i filter 'member' will return

```
[{
    "groupID": 111,
    "name": "member",
    "remarks": "access group name"
}]
```

Then when i filter 'access' will return

```
[{
    "groupID": 1,
    "name": "admin",
    "remarks": "access group name,"
},
{
    "groupID": 111,
    "name": "member",
    "remarks": "access group name"
}]
```

How to do that? Thank you stackoverflow

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please include any code you wrote?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code service. Please update your question with your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Use array filter to parse through the objects in the array and search for the keyword.

```
const search =(arr, word)=>{
  return arr.filter(item =>{
  return Object.values(item).join().includes(word) 
})

}
```